# "STOP! Look and Listen" for trying to edit a bad answer in the first posts queue

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19679618) is the answer in question. I clicked "edit" from the review queue and failed the review.

I understand that this is a low-quality answer, and maybe this is subject to debate, but I think this could be edited to be at least a *plausibly somewhat useful* answer. Getting a failure for trying to edit it was a bit shocking to me.

Given the degree to which this seems to reduce to a matter of opinion about what might be a recoverable answer and what isn't, shouldn't trying to edit a post like this not trigger an outright review queue failure?

Comment: I'm not even sure why that answer got deleted. I mean it is bad but as far as I can tell it does answer the question. It isn't worth keeping as the other answers do a much better job at explaining that feature, still ...

Comment: Seems like it was used in one other audit and both failed... It was voted to delete [uninanimously](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19606403) >10k link

Comment: Answers that were deleted with only 1 downvote doesn't seem like good candidates for audits.

Comment: @rene probably because it doesn't add anything over existing answers.

Comment: @Braiam agree on that but IIRC that type of answers shouldn't be deleted from review, they shouldn't have been flagged in the first place. They are not garbage and they are answering a question. Downvote, yes, delete vote, sure. Flag? No.

Comment: @rene well, at least one of the users was a 20k user that casted a vtd. How would said user cast that vote if he didn't rely on the queue to find it?

Comment: @Braiam watching their tags? 10K tools?

Comment: I just saw a related post on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310055/158100

Comment: @rene 10k tools only shows those that *already* have a delete vote, ie. if there's no one that gets the ball rolling, it woulnd't appear there. So, that's not an option. And... you know how many active where in the [tag:eclipse] at the moment + all the other tags the user may answer question to? The /review was meant to use a little time that you have available for moderation to pressing issues. How many close votes you can cast accurately without helping tools, just relying on the /active tag?

Comment: @Braiam I've found other ways ... can we keep it on-topic before we end-up  in exchanging rants?

Comment: @rene well, post that on meta, because I'm sure interested and others would too. Without *relying on other users reports*, there's simply too much time wasted just trying to look for where to apply moderator actions effectively and efficiently.

Comment: This is yet another example demonstrating that the automatic creation of audit posts is prone to creating unfair audits. :( Without the context of the existing answers a reviewer doesn't know it replicates existing answers. It just looks like an attempt at an answer from a user with poor English skills that needs a little bit of editing to polish it up.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, but it doesn't *matter* that bogus audits happen occasionally - they're rare enough that you can keep reviewing, it just causes confusion.

Comment: That is definitely an answer. Lorry doesn't use good English but does tell us about the tabs. Are we now just willy-nilly deleting answers that we don't like? Seems like a slippery slope to be on, but it could be great fun - imagine how much we could clean up?

Comment: @o11c well, until you fail the audit and get locked out of the review queues for a week.

Comment: @Venantius You don't get locked out for one failed audit. While some incorrect audits do exist, it is by no means a given they get you banned if you review carefully. Ftr, I have completed over 10000 review tasks including my share of invalid audits without getting review banned *ever*.

Comment: @PM2Ring *"Without the context of the existing answers a reviewer doesn't know it replicates existing answers."* At least the number of other answers is displayed prominently next to the answer in question, and the age and number of views of the question is on screen, too. Checking if a new answer to such an old and popular question is actually original or maybe a plag does not sound like too much of a stretch to me, especially given the displayed score of the answer. I would not be so fast to absolve OP here, this was not un-catchable at all.

Comment: (Although I agree that this answer should not have been deleted from the LQQ to begin with.)